# Nearest neighbor POSTGIS in FME

Tags: postgis, fme-form

I have an attribute and I want to find the nearest neighbor but the issue is that the memory of the server may not be able to handle the use of all the FME transformers.  I need to take records out of a POSTGIS table and compare them to the records I have to find the nearest neighbor.  I am thinking of using ST_ClosestPoint but not sure how to write that.  If anyone has used this before it would be great to get an idea.

Comment: The both geometries you try to "relate/measure", are they in th same PostGIS DB or is one geo feature in an external source and the other one in a PostGIS DB.

Comment: You can use SQL Executor in FME to get the database to do the  ST_ClosestPoint and return the values for FME to process further  https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/19649/performing-native-spatial-queries-on-database-tabl.html